# $_SESSION values lost after a header('Location: .........')

Tags: php, session

Here is my code :

```
$login      = $_SESSION['login'];
$statut     = $_SESSION['statut'];
$atelier    = $_SESSION['atelier'];
$connexion  = $_SESSION['connexion'];
session_destroy ();
$_SESSION['login']      = $login;
$_SESSION['statut']     = $statut;
$_SESSION['atelier']    = $atelier;
$_SESSION['connexion']  = true;
header('Location: http://10.13.48.60/no_serie.php');
```

Soo when I arrive here, the header send me to the correct page but I loose each time my login value like if it didn't save again my $_SESSION value.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Or an another solution would be to put the variables in the link like :

```
header('Location: http://10.13.48.60/no_serie.php?login = '.$login.', statut = '.$statut.', ...');
```

But I prefer the `$_SESSION` solution.

ps : I start each of my page with `session_start();` and I never touch to the `$_SESSION` value.

Thanks

Comment: Could you post code of `no_serie.php` file?

Comment: Are you calling [session_start()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before this code?

Comment: after session_destroy ();, start the session again or dont destroy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You called `session_destroy()` then set more sessions, so you need to make sure `session_start()` is called again before resetting the sessions. Or don't call `session_destroy` at all.

Like so:

```
$login      = $_SESSION['login'];
$statut     = $_SESSION['statut'];
$atelier    = $_SESSION['atelier'];
$connexion  = $_SESSION['connexion'];

// session_destroy (); - unnecessary

$_SESSION['login']      = $login;
$_SESSION['statut']     = $statut;
$_SESSION['atelier']    = $atelier;
$_SESSION['connexion']  = true;
header('Location: http://10.13.48.60/no_serie.php');
```

From PHP.net:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie. To use the session variables again, session_start() has to be called.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

Comment: I didn't knew I had to do again a session_start after the destroy. Thanks a lot. I had to do the destroy to "kill" all others $_SESSION variables, there is more to "kill" than to save, thats why I do this way.

Answer (score 1):

You destroy the complete session but you dont (re)start it.

```
session_destroy();
session_start();
```